# Unable to install cint on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, libraries, configure

I am trying to build [cint](http://root.cern.ch/drupal/content/cint) from sources on Ubuntu 12.04. However it complains about `libreadline`:

```
~/Desktop/cint-5.18.00 » ./configure      
Guessing architecture to be linuxx8664gcc
Using current CINT core
Please install the package "libreadline or [lib]readline-dev[el]"!
```

I have `libreadline6`, `libreadline-dev` and `libreadline6-dev` installed. What should I do?

#### Edit:

Using `--readlinelib` option below I am able to run `configure`, `make` and `make install`:

```
/usr/local/include/cint
/usr/local/include/cint/cintdictversion.h
/usr/local/include/cint/configcint.h
/usr/local/share/cint
/usr/local/share/cint/cint
/usr/local/share/cint/cint/lib/qt/qtcint.h
/usr/local/share/cint/cint/lib/wintcldl83/cintlib.c
/usr/local/share/cint/cint/lib/socket/cintsock.h
/usr/local/share/cint/cint/lib/socket/cintsock.c
/usr/local/share/cint/cint/lib/dll_stl/cinteh.h
/usr/local/share/cint/cint/lib/win32api/cintwin.h
/usr/local/share/cint/cint/lib/gl/cintGL.h
/usr/local/share/cint/cint/lib/cintocx
/usr/local/share/cint/cint/lib/cintocx/cintocx.aps
/usr/local/share/cint/cint/lib/cintocx/cintocx.h
/usr/local/share/cint/cint/lib/cintocx/cintocx.cpp
/usr/local/share/cint/cint/lib/cintocx/cintocx.ico
/usr/local/share/cint/cint/lib/cintocx/CintocxCtl.cpp
/usr/local/share/cint/cint/lib/cintocx/CintocxCtl.bmp
/usr/local/share/cint/cint/lib/cintocx/cintocx3.bmp
/usr/local/share/cint/cint/lib/cintocx/cintocx.clw
/usr/local/share/cint/cint/lib/cintocx/CintocxCtl.h
/usr/local/share/cint/cint/lib/cintocx/CintocxPpg.h
/usr/local/share/cint/cint/lib/cintocx/cintocx.mdp
/usr/local/share/cint/cint/lib/cintocx/cintocx.odl
/usr/local/share/cint/cint/lib/cintocx/CintocxPpg.cpp
/usr/local/share/cint/cint/lib/cintocx/cintocx.mak
/usr/local/share/cint/cint/lib/cintocx/Cint-Ocx
/usr/local/share/cint/cint/lib/cintocx/cintocx.rc
/usr/local/share/man/man1/makecint.1
/usr/local/share/man/man1/cint.1
/usr/local/lib/libCint.so
/usr/local/lib/libCint_static.a
/usr/local/lib/clang/3.5/include/f16cintrin.h
/usr/local/bin/cint
/usr/local/bin/cint-config
/usr/local/bin/makecint
```

But when I try to run it I get:

```
~/Desktop/cint-5.18.00 » cint
cint: error while loading shared libraries: libCint.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Thanks

Comment: Could you please put some of your time to review the answer? You may edit or add new one.

Comment: I have built and installed it using `checkinstall` but it tells me `bin/cint: error while loading shared libraries: libCint.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Comment: `locate libCint.so`? (extend the question with the output, please, don't use comments for that)

Comment: `locate` returns only local version of the library.. I tried to run `sudo make install`. I have posted the error above, thanks.

Comment: Weird, it works for me. Try the new ./configure with --prefix option.

Comment: It doesn't work, neither with `--prefix=/usr/local` nor `--prefix`

Comment: `find /usr/local -iname *cint*`, append output to the question?

Comment: It seems `/usr/local/lib` is not in ld load path. see my edit

Comment: It now works, thanks :) How to put /usr/local/lib in the ld load path?

Comment: Add it to `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/` see update

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Search for shared lib using using:

  ```
  locate libreadline.so
  ```

  Then run configure with `--readlinelib` option:

  ```
  ./configure --readlinelib=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libreadline.so.6 --prefix=/usr/local
  make
  sudo make install
  ```
- If cint couldn't find the shared lib `libCint.so`.

  ```
  sudo ln /usr/local/lib/libCint.so /usr/lib/libCint.so
  ```

  or you may add `/usr/local/lib` to ld load path:

  ```
  sudo echo "/usr/local/lib" >> /etc/ld.so.conf.d/usr-local.conf
  sudo ldconfig
  ```

  But keep in mind this not recommended, Local installed lib's may conflict with Distribution installed libs. So make links instead if you get such problems.
- If it didn't work.  There are multiple readline lib versions. see if they work.

  If your OS is 64bit install:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install lib64readline6-dev:i386
  ```

  I have checked it and it does work. Otherwise check the other one of 32bit:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install lib32readline6-dev
  ```

Comment: This is weird.. I have a 64 bit install `Linux desktop 3.5.0-45-generic #68~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Dec 4 16:18:46 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux` but the first solution you proposed has unmet dependencies.. the second can be installed.. is it possible to install the second without breaking a 64 bit install?

Comment: If apt did not mention other lib in 'packages to be removed' then they can be installed beside each other without any conflict. You can check also using Synaptic tool in dependency tab if they have conflict.

Comment: I installed it.. However configure still does not find `libreadline`.. am I missing anything?

Comment: I searched and libreadline shows up in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libreadline.a` and `/usr/lib32/libreadline.a`.. maybe I need to refresh a libraries paths cache?

Comment: Yeah may be. you may try `./configure --readlinelib=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libreadline.so.6`. Search for shared lib using `locate libreadline.so`

Comment: using `--readlinelib` works.. Thanks. My package list is current.

Answer (score 1):

**How to install cint onto a 64 bit Ubuntu 12.10 box.  Here is how I did it:**

1. Make a new directory `/home/el/foo`
2. Go into the directory and checkout the latest and greatest:

   ```
   svn co http://root.cern.ch/svn/root/branches/v5-34-00-patches/cint cint
   cd cint
   sudo apt-get install libreadline-dev
   ./configure --readlinelib=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libreadline.so.6.2 --prefix=/usr/local

   make
   sudo make install
   sudo ln /usr/local/lib/libCint.so /usr/lib/libCint.so
   ```
3. Then run it:

   ```
   el@apollo:~/foo/cint$ cint

   cint : C/C++ interpreter  (mailing list 'root-cint@cern.ch')
      Copyright(c) : 1995~2010 Masaharu Goto (gotom@hanno.jp)
      revision     : 5.18.00, July 2, 2010 by M.Goto

   No main() function found in given source file. Interactive interface started.
   'h':help, 'q':quit, '{statements;}' or 'p [expr]' to evaluate

   cint> sin(1.2);
   (const double)1.19999999999999996e+00
   ```
4. There are tutorials on the main site.

   ```
   cint> printf("ok");
   (const char* 0x16bef60)"ok"
   ```